# 3d Model In Flutter with GLB, OBJ, or GLTF file

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, blender

I have a simple question - how do I integrate a 3d model into flutter from blender with a GLB, OBJ, or GLTF file? It is a complex and big model, but I want it to render fast and efficiently.

Things I tried:
I have tried using the Flutter_3d Library, the Babylon JS Library (couldn't get it to work), and some deprecated libraries that I didn't know were deprecated. I really need help with this as its the main part of my app. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have a WebView that uses ThreeJS to display your model.  Check out https://github.com/ColtonBristow/FlutterThreeJS.

Google also showed off new capabilities of Impeller that should be coming soon.  Watch https://flutter.dev/events/flutter-forward

Comment: Wow! I can't wait until Impeller comes out for android and ios! And I think threeJS would be a great solution. Do you think you could provide an example script? I see the example in the threeJS github but am not sure how to specify the .glb file. Thank you so much!

Comment: That ThreeJSViewer is a bit confusing because you pass the model in wrapped in a list.   So,  ThreeJSViewer( models: [ThreeModel(src: 'https://URL_TO_YOUR_MODEL', playAnimation: true)] ).  I also noticed that the threeJS_Viewer/web/index.js file uses some "cors anywhere" web service to filter off the CORS headers from your URL response in its loadModel function.  You'd probably want to remove that or provide your own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ModelViewerPlus from pub.dev - [ModelViewerPlus](https://pub.dev/packages/model_viewer_plus)
Just follow the instructions on the package page. Here's an example:

```
InteractiveViewer(
        scaleEnabled: true,
        scaleFactor: 150,
        panEnabled: true,
        child: ModelViewer(
          src: 'assets/models/car.glb',
        ),
      ),
```